# New line in Meteor HTTP POST

Tags: http, post, meteor, newline

What is the correct way to insert a new line in a Meteor.http POST call?

Here's what I usually do:

```
var result = HTTP.call("POST", URL, {
                params: {
                  field: value
                },
                headers:{
                    "[HEADER FIELD]":"[HEADER VALUE]"
                }
            });
```

I want the value in this case to be multiple strings separated by new lines. I have tried:

```
value = "firstItem" + "%0A" + secondItem + "%0A" + thirdItem
```

The API I am using expects value to be different items, each on a new line. When I post this request, the API consumes this as a string and doesn't identify the items as separate inputs. Any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of API expects values to be a string with new line? This sounds pretty crazy. Are you sure it is what is expected and that it's not expecting an Array instead? 
Have you tried `\n` for a new line?

Comment: Yea it was new to me too. It's a Mashape API and using "%0D%0A" to separate the items works in the Mashape test console but not from Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

A POST request usually has it's parameters separated by & if you're using application/x-www-form-urlencoded:

```
parameter=value&also=another
```

That being said, if you use application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the W3C spec states that "%0D%0A" is a new line so you can try that too.

https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1

Comment: I've tried "%0D%0A" in addition to the "%0A" I wrote in the question. Works in the test console but not from Meteor.http.

Comment: Have you specified the content type in your response header? It must be "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: Yes, specified the content-type